# JTable same component for renderer and editor

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I use a JTable in my application. The table uses a custom renderer to display components in the cells e.g. buttons. Everything works fine except if I click on a row, the button in the row disappears.
I've read that I should use different instances of a component.
One for rendering and another one for editation.

**But why do I need to do this?**

I want to use the same instance for rendering and editing.

Comment: The answer can be found in the [documentation for SwingUtilities.paintComponent](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingUtilities.html#paintComponent-java.awt.Graphics-java.awt.Component-java.awt.Container-int-int-int-int-):  A renderer gets re-parented to a CellRendererPane, so you can't expect it to stay in the container to which you've added it.

Answer (score 1):

> Everything works fine except if I click on a row, the button in the row disappears.

Well an editor is a real component that gets added to the table in the area of the cell. This component can receive events and the user can interact with it.

A renderer is just used to paint an image of the component.

So somewhere in the logic of how a table works the single component can't be used for two different functions. That would be a poor design. You should never have a class or object used for two different things.

In any case the simple solution is to use two components.

Check out [Table Button Column](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/07/12/table-button-column/) for a solution that also uses two buttons. I realized the same problem when I was working on this as well.

Comment: When a renderer is **just used to paint an image of the component**, so why is there a problem when using one component for both?

Comment: @ben look at the source code to see exactly what the code is doing. I don't know exactly. But in order to even render a cell you need to change the properties of the component so who knows what confusion is going on. In any case you should NOT use a class for two different functions. You seemed to miss that part of the answer.

Comment: No, I don't missed that part. But I don't think that these are **functions**, which **needs** to be separated. Here, something similar is provided: http://www.jidesoft.com/javadoc/com/jidesoft/grid/TableCellEditorRenderer.html

Comment: @Ben, did you read VGR's comment? That sparks a memory. If I remember correctly the "cell renderer pane" is used to make painting more efficient. The detail is in the implementation like I already stated.

Comment: No, I really missed that comment. Thank you! So the renderer is not just painted (that was my problem to understand).